# column to span \paperwidth in beamer footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, positioning

In the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=4ex, left]{author in head/foot}%                                                                                                                              
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
      \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\paperwidth}|p{0.5\paperwidth}|}
        entry00 & entry01
      \end{tabular}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  frame contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I try to create a table in a beamer footline to span the width of a beamer frame. The result is not satisfactory as I cannot see the rightmost margin of the table:

[image]

How to fix the solution?

Comment: Why do you want to use a table in the footline?

Comment: @samcarter, to position different fields at predefined places. Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: I added an answer without tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were just two things wrong with your code:

1. There was an extra implicit space after `\hbox{`. I fixed it by adding a `%` after it.
2. The `0.5\paperwidth` is the width of the text. It does not include the `\tabcolsep`, which separates the text from the vertical rules. I have set it to zero to make the column with exactly `0.5\paperwidth`.

Also, as you noted yourself, there is no apparent need for the `\hbox`, so I removed it

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=4ex, left]{author in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\paperwidth}|p{0.5\paperwidth}|}
      entry00 & entry01
    \end{tabular}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  frame contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Another option to the second problem is to reduce the width of the column by `2\tabcolsep` to make it fit, like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=4ex, left]{author in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
      entry00 & entry01
    \end{tabular}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  frame contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The second option looks better because the text doesn't run over the vertical rule. But if you *must* have the text running in `0.5\paperwidth` then the first one is what you want.

Comment: Do we need the `\hbox` at all?

Comment: @Viesturs Good question. Hold on, I'll check... No, the `\hbox` has no use there, apparently. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use a table to place different fields besides each other in the footline. In normal beamer themes, this effect is achieved by simply placing several `beamercolorbox`es besides each other:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\author{names}
\title{title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  frame contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Depending on what you are actually going to add to the footline, the `hackthefootline` might be a simple alternative:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[twocols]{hackthefootline}

\author{names}
\title{title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  frame contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```