# Add white space after table entry

Tags: tables

In this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
  entry00 & entry01\quad
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I try to add some white space after `entry01` by using `\quad`. In the result the white space has been completely ignored:

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: don't set `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`. why you do this?

Comment: @Zarko exactly to illustrate that `\quad` got ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, from your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412094/134574), that you *have* to use the `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`, so you can add a `\null` anchor to trick TeX into accepting your space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
  entry00 & entry01\quad\null
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r@{\quad}|}% <---
  entry00 & entry01
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @samcarter, this year i'm not candidate. two years is sufficient :-). it is time to new (younger) TeX enthusiasts.

Comment: OK, an understandable reason.

Answer (score 4):

End-of-line spaces/skips are usually gobbled. If you wish to force them to remain, consider using `\hspace` or `\hspace*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{l |} }
  entry00 & entry01\quad & entry02\hspace{1em} & entry03\hspace*{1em}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`\quad` is a `\h`orizontal `skip` of length `1em`.